# Why Sum of Squares were different between Stata anova and SAS glm?

Tags: sas, stata

```
anova y group hop

                       Number of obs =     206     R-squared     =  0.0331
                       Root MSE      = 20.0345     Adj R-squared =  0.0139

              Source |  Partial SS    df       MS           F     Prob > F
          -----------+----------------------------------------------------
               Model |  2761.85468     4  690.463671       1.72     0.1469
                     |
               group |  42.2798948     1  42.2798948       0.11     0.7459
                 hop |  2633.73186     3  877.910619       2.19     0.0907
                     |
            Residual |  80677.5664   201  401.380927   
          -----------+----------------------------------------------------
               Total |  83439.4211   205  407.021566   



 proc glm data=ccc;
    class group hop;
    model y=group hop;
    run;
                                                               Sum of
Source               DF         Squares     Mean Square    F Value    Pr > F

Model                 4      2761.79407       690.44852       1.72    0.1469

Error               201     80677.50607       401.38063

Corrected Total     205     83439.30014


      R-Square     Coeff Var      Root MSE    hbalcv27 Mean

      0.033099      129.8628      20.03449         15.42743


Source       DF       Type I SS     Mean Square    F Value    Pr > F
group         1      128.138891      128.138891       0.32    0.5727
HOP           3     2633.655176      877.885059       2.19    0.0907


Source       DF     Type III SS     Mean Square    F Value    Pr > F
group        1       42.289824       42.289824       0.11    0.7458
HOP          3     2633.655176      877.885059       2.19    0.0907
```

Comment: This isn't a programming question; you should ask the question at [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), or perhaps even better at the help sites of the respective programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the  storage precision is not the same in the SAS and Stata data sets.  The computations could also be done in different precisions. I don't know about SAS, but according to this [blog](http://blog.stata.com/tag/precision/#section8) by Bill Gould:

```
Stata does all calculations in double (and sometimes quad) precision.
```

Comment: SAS also uses doubles.  You should look at the way your are getting your data into each system.  At the end of the day, the numbers are not all the different.  Slight changes in how the data are read from the source could account for this small difference.

Comment: Many thanks.You can download stata and sas datasets from http://pan.baidu.com/s/101x3M

Comment: @stata Hm, that site is all in Chinese, and appears to require a downloader, which I can't figure out.